# Почему строка root.getChildren().add(start.load()); выдает исключение InvocationTargetException и как это можно исправить?

Tags: javafx, fxml

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException {
        Main.stage = primaryStage;
        FXMLLoader start = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/src/main/resources/introduction.fxml"));
        root.getChildren().add(start.load());

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setTitle("Русские шашки");
        stage.getIcons().add(new Image("icon.png"));
        stage.setResizable(false);

        newGame.setOnAction(event -> Introduction.startGame());
}
```

Comment: А кто такой `root`  и где его инициализация?

Comment: Может должно быть так: `Parent root = start.load();`?

Comment: root просто задан в начале                                                                                   
public static Group root = new Group();

Comment: Если я правильно на память помню, в getChilden добавляются node, а group может им и не являться.

Comment: Менч ещё `static` смущает, нужен простой воспроизводимый пример